# inserting multiple row at time in sqlite

Tags: android

I just created a method to insert into the database. But it still showing the same result. i,e unit1 only. the code is as follows
DbAdapter.java

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="bible1";
 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="test1";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

 public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
 public static final String UNITS="units";
 public static final String CHAPTERS="chapters";

 private static final String CREATE_DATABASE="create table test1 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, units text not null, chapters text not null);";

 private static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private Context context;

 //constructor

 public DbAdapter(Context c){
     context = c;
 }

 private static class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     public SQLiteHelper(Context context){

         super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
     }
     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
         MakeUnits();
     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

 }

 public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
     try{
     sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
     sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     }catch(NullPointerException ne){
         Log.e("Database", "error in creating the table");
     }

     return this;
 }

 public void close(){
     sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public static void MakeUnits()
 {
     createUnits("unit1","chapter1");
     createUnits("unit2","chapter2");  
 }

 public Cursor fetchAllNotes(){
     return sqLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID,UNITS,CHAPTERS}, null, null, null, null, null);
 }

 public static long createUnits(String units,String chapters){
     ContentValues content= new ContentValues();
     content.put(UNITS, units);
     content.put(CHAPTERS, chapters);
     return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, content);

 }
```

So What to do now? I think the method I created is correct.

Comment: I think you can't. You have to gone through loop for inserting multiple data in database. As insert query of SQLite is handled only one row at a time.

Comment: Please check the above modified code and please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your insertion as below:

```
public static long MakeUnits(SQLiteDatabase db)
 {
     long total = 0;

     ContentValues insert1 = new ContentValues();
     insert1.put(UNITS, "Unit1");
     insert1.put(CHAPTERS, "CHAPTER1");
     total = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,insert1);

     insert1.clear();
     insert1.put(UNITS, "Unit2");
     insert1.put(CHAPTERS, "CHAPTER2");
     total += db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,insert1);

     return total;
 }
```

Preferably, I would suggest you to use some sort of **Loop** to get multiple insertions done.

Comment: I changed the code as follows by creating the method createUnit()

Comment: Yes. But still showing one item. You can have a look at the code above that I modified.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multiple rows with one insert. However, you can make multiple inserts  efficient using `InsertHelper` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html